# I have two images in Bitmap format and want to overlay one with 50% transparency over the other one

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bufferedimage

So as stated in the headline,
given: two Bitmaps
wanted: one Bitmap with both images mixed together.

Is there a way to do this on android? I've thought about converting both maps to bufferedImages and then overlapping and transforming back to `Bitmap` but that doesn't seem to work on android. I'm still fairly new to all this.

Basically the bitmaps that are saved at `currentImagePath1` and `currentImagePath2`. Here's the java code:

```java
package com.example.cameraexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String currentImagePath1 = null;
    String currentImagePath2 = null;
    ImageView imageView;
    int pic = 1;
    private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void captureImage1(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            File imageFile = null;

            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile1();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(imageFile != null) {
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", imageFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_REQUEST);

            }
        }
    }

    public void captureImage2(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            File imageFile = null;

            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile2();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(imageFile != null) {
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", imageFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }

    /*public void displayImageBackup(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayImage.class);
       intent.putExtra("image_path", currentImagePath);
       startActivity(intent);
    }*/

    public void displayImage1(View view) {
        showImage(currentImagePath1);
    }

    public void displayImage2(View view) {
        showImage(currentImagePath2);
    }

    private File getImageFile1() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String imageName = "1_jps_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir  = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        currentImagePath1 = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }

    private File getImageFile2() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String imageName = "2_jps_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir  = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        currentImagePath2 = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }

    public void showImage(String image_path) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.mimageView);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public void overlay(View view) {
    }

    public void switch_images(View view) {
        if(pic == 1) displayImage2(view);
        if(pic == 2) displayImage1(view);

        if(pic == 1) pic = 2;
        else pic = 1;
    }
}
```

Testing didn't really show any helpful results for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much to user1506104 for pointing out a solution to my problem. Sorry for the late reply, I had a few things going on in my life that couldn't wait.

I can just put two ImageViews ontop of each other. :)

It worked like the follogwing: To overlay i made another method like the showImage just that the ImageView it projected the bitmap to had an alpha of 0.5. The mistake was that I had to delete this line: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 1):

How about creating two `ImageView` that overlap each other by putting them in a `FrameLayout`. Then set 50% alpha value to the top image like so:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/a"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/b"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Well now it only shows one of the images at 50% opacity. Not the second one underneath it (I used a different ImageView obcourse)

Comment: how about giving a 0.5 alpha as well to your bottom ImageView? or try to play around with the alpha values of the two overlapping image views.

Comment: It worked like the follogwing: To overlay i made another method like the showImage just that the ImageView it projected the bitmap to had an alpha of 0.5. The mistake was that I had to delete this line: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Cool. Please add your solution as an answer so you can close this out.